# How to tell if my system's Nvidia GeForce FX 5500 graphics card driver is suitable or not?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, lubuntu

I am a pretty new user for Linux-like systems and I have installed Lubuntu 17.10 on an old desktop machine which has an Nvidia GeForce FX 5500 graphics card. But I have no idea if the graphics card driver installed suits that device or not. How can I determine if I am using the right driver?

I looked for Nvidia’s own drivers for the Nvidia GeForce FX 5500, which came out to be `nvidia-173`. Am I supposed to be installing that? I have read that it won’t be available after Ubuntu 14.x?

Earlier I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and it felt miserably slow with GUI operations so I am concerned if my graphics card driver is the proper one for this card.

I run Windows XP on that same machine with no problems related to graphics.

Comment: Seems like my best bet would be installing Xubuntu 14.04 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/155572), the latest drivers are at version 173.14.35. Since `.deb` packages are provided on that page, you can install them via the [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html) command which helps manages packages made for the [Debian Package Management System](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html). Just do the following…

First, open up a terminal and download those `.deb` packages via Wget:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173-updates/173.14.35-0ubuntu1/+build/3597638/+files/nvidia-173-updates-dev_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173-updates/173.14.35-0ubuntu1/+build/3597638/+files/nvidia-173-updates_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Once you have those download those packages, install them via the `dpkg` command with the `-i` flag like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-173-updates-dev_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-173-updates_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

And then, I would recommend reboot your system and seeing what happens. This should be fine.

If not, you can remove those packages by running the `dpkg` command again with the `-r` flag like this:

```
sudo dpkg -r nvidia-173-updates-dev_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -r nvidia-173-updates_173.14.35-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me but that package too seems like it is for ubuntu 12 precise only, wouldn't that be bad for me?